# bash resolve service name

Tags: linux, bash, netcat

As part of a start script I need to check to see if a particular TCP service is actually up and running. By reading a config file I know what the target host and service name is. I intended to use **nc** to send a sample request to this service, because I know how to use it and it scripts well, the problem is that **nc** cannot resolve the service name in my config to a port number...

Which brings me to my (2-part) question:
Is there a bash built-in or commonly distributed utility (would be part or a RHEL 5 distro) which can resolve the service name to a port number?
Is there a simple utility other than netcat which I could use in my script instead?

Comment: You should consider preferring socat.

Comment: @jørgensen I will definitely check it out for future use, but it is not available on my target system and the pain of deploying it will be far worse than the worst case of grepping the port number out of the services file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getent` is what you want.

For instance: `getent services ftp`

You'll need to parse the output anyway, but you have the port.

Comment: I was really hoping not to have the parse the output... but this seems to be the best option at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Is there **/etc/services** file in your system? Probably every portable program (including `nc`, `getent` and many others) uses `getservbyname(3)` to resolve port number for the given service name. In turn, that function reads the data from `/etc/services` file.

Comment: There is an **/etc/services** file and I'm aware of what it contains. I specifically want to avoid grepping the value I need out of there and parsing it.

Comment: You don't need grepping anything. The standard libc function `getservbyname` does it. And as I said, almost all programs uses this function to get a port number for the given service. And `nc` too! Right now I temporarily removed /etc/services on my system and `nc` could not resolve a services by name. For example, the command `nc localhost ssh` gives: `invalid port ssh : No such file or directory`. When I restored /etc/services file, the referred command could run successfully. So, whether the content of your /etc/services file is correct? And does it contains the necessary service names?

Comment: I am aware of the `getservbyname` function, and the role that the `/etc/services` file plays. Unfortunately the version of nc that is installed on our servers (1.84) does not resolve services: `nc localhost ssh` returns: `nc: port range not valid` while `getservbyname` returns 22. I should have been more specific about the version of `nc` I had available.